# I want to remove warning: "Replace this with a lock against an object with strong-identity"

Tags: c#, .net, com

I have an ActiveX COM object that is used to play video and its being used in a C# application.  It is declared like so:

```
private AxVIDEOPLAYERUILib.AxVideoPlayerUI axVideoPlayerUI;
```

In my code there are locks on this like so:

```
lock (axVideoPlayerUI)
{
     axVideoPlayerUI.EnableControls = 1;
     axVideoPlayerUI.Visible = true;
     axVideoPlayerUI.ShowOverlay = 1;
     axVideoPlayerUI.OverlayPosition = 3;
     axVideoPlayerUI.Play();         
 }
```

But I get warnings that I want to get rid of:

> Warning   1   CA2002 : Microsoft.Reliability :
>   'VideoPlayerControl.LoadRecording(RecordVideo, int)' locks on a
>   reference of type 'AxVideoPlayerUI'. Replace this with a lock against
>   an object with strong-identity.

From this link here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182290.aspx it states that the following objects have a weak identity:

MarshalByRefObject, ExecutionEngineException, OutOfMemoryException, StackOverflowException, String, MemberInfo, ParameterInfo, Thread.

But my object doesnt fall into any of these categories.

I have also tried making my object **static** as described here: [C# lock and code analysis warning CA2002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613588/c-sharp-lock-and-code-analysis-warning-ca2002) but that gives me errors:

> Error 1   Member 'MyNameSpace.VideoPlayerControl.axVideoPlayerUI' cannot
>   be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name
>   instead

Does anyone know how I can get rid of the original warning??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just declare a separate object to use for locking:

```
private AxVIDEOPLAYERUILib.AxVideoPlayerUI axVideoPlayerUI;
private object axVideoPlayerUILock = new object();
```

and:

```
lock (axVideoPlayerUILock)
{
   ...
```

---

COM Proxies are implemented by `System.__ComObject`, which in turn derives from `MarshalByRefObject`. Perhaps the guidance could be clearer that types *derived* from those mentioned are also not usable.

Comment: The documentation for [marshallByRefObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.marshalbyrefobject?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) seems to just show how to create a new object of that type from another applicationdomain. So the private field here still cannot be accessed from outside, and hence the warning is incorrect - it should only fire when you lock on one of those types, not on a private variable of that type.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn - when compiling *a* method, the compiler doesn't tend to perform full escape analysis over all fields of classes that it's working with. There's no way *locally* to determine the lifetime of the object referenced by that variable. But it's a warning not an error precisely because it cannot prove that its incorrectly used either.